# How to pass a object from sequelize to a handlebars partial?

Tags: node.js, view, sequelize.js, handlebars.js, partials

i am using handlebars version 4.7.6 and sequelize 5.21.5 to make a blog app.
I need to pass a post object ( post.id, post.title and post.content ) that i get with sequelize to a form, but the form is a partial.
I try to use

```
{{> formPost post=post }}
```

and

```
{{> formPost post }}
```

but its dont work. the form is displayed and single variables like

```
{{> formPost myvar="blablabla" }}
```

works fine.

How is the correct way ?

Answer (score 1):

Well, i discover that the sequelize has a security block on object. 
The way to pass sequelize objects to handlebars is creating a json object from sequelize object.